# Java - Opencv VideoCapture.read - Exception in thread java.lang.exception : Unknown Exception

Tags: java, multithreading, exception, opencv, video-processing

I have a java program that runs a webcam and capture images with the use of opencv libraries. My camera is working and eventually stops taking frames. It throws an exception.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-11" java.lang.Exception: unknown exception
at org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture.read_0(Native Method)
at org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture.read(VideoCapture.java:341)
at projectana.VideoThread.run(VideoThread.java:59)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

---

Here is my code:

(VideoThread.java)

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import org.opencv.core.Core;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.core.MatOfRect;
import org.opencv.core.Point;
import org.opencv.core.Rect;
import org.opencv.core.Scalar;
import org.opencv.highgui.VideoCapture;
import org.opencv.objdetect.CascadeClassifier;

/**
 * @author DEV-OJT
 */

public class VideoThread implements Runnable {

    static private DoVideo vid;
    static private boolean running;

    public VideoThread(DoVideo vid) {
        this.vid = vid;
        running = true;
    }

    protected static void terminate() {
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // CascadeClassifier faceDetector = new CascadeClassifier(this.getClass().
        // getResource("/resources/haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml").getPath());
        Mat webcam_image = new Mat();

        BufferedImage temp;
        VideoCapture capture = new VideoCapture(0);
        if (capture.isOpened()) {
            System.err.println("Sleeping..");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                System.err.println("cant sleep");
            }
            System.err.println("camera opened");
            while (running) {
                System.out.println("entered");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    System.err.println("cant sleep");
                }
                capture.read(webcam_image);
                if (!webcam_image.empty()) {
                    // MatOfRect faceDetections = new MatOfRect();
                    // faceDetector.detectMultiScale(webcam_image, faceDetections);
                    // System.out.println("Number of Faces Detected: "+faceDetections.toArray().length);
                    // for(Rect rect : faceDetections.toArray()){
                    //    System.out.println(rect.toString());
                    //    Core.rectangle(webcam_image, new Point(rect.x, rect.y), 
                    //       new Point(rect.x + rect.width, rect.y + rect.height),
                    //    new Scalar(0, 255, 0));
                    // }
                    temp = Helper.matToBufferedImage(webcam_image);
                    vid.setimage(temp);
                    vid.repaint();
                } else {
                    System.out.println(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!");
                    //break;  
                }
            }
        } else {
            System.err.println("No Camera.");
        }
    }

}
```

My code in stopping the the thread in SnapshotDialog.java every formWindowClosed event:

```
if (snapshot != null) {
    VideoThread.terminate();
    try {
        snapshot.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(SnapshotDialog.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    System.err.println("Successfully stop thread.");
} else {
    System.err.println("Unsuccessfully stop thread.");
}
snapshot = null;
```

Why does it operates at first and eventually stops taking frames when I open the dialog box in 5 or less tries? Is it the opencv library or wrong coding and management of threads or just, my camera is tired and needs rest. Thank you masters. Java beginner here :)

Comment: are you seeing "cant sleep" in the output before the exception ?

Comment: No, i dont see "cant sleep" its just i place it for clarification when debugging there is nothing wrong on my thread.sleep though

Comment: Also, that Exception above sometimes don't appear but still the application is still running when closed

Comment: What are you doing in the `snapshot` thread

Comment: I've used thread.interrupt and it works! thanks! and also i now see the "cant sleep" because the thread interrupts right? ok thank you very much!

Comment: it takes a frame from a webcam and paste it in a panel. but sometimes it stops catching frames and the video feed stops. It was before doing the interrupt method. I don't know now if it will still show.

Comment: Well you `terminate` the Video thread then join the feed. Then you may call read on your camera however you closed the video feed in the Video thread. The error is happening on the VIDEO isOpen c interface.

Comment: No, its happening while the thread is on the run. It just stop capturing frames when i frequently opening the video thread. It just stops suddenly.

Comment: It runs for a while and stops after a few seconds.