# java - My application is still running in task manager even my java program is closed or stop in application in netbeans

Tags: java, multithreading, opencv, netbeans, webcam-capture

Whenever I use my webcam application within the main form, the program does not closed and still appearing in the task manager or in the bottom right of the Netbeans saying that it is still running even if I clicked **STOP** or close my form. It only occurs when I access my Webcam snapshot application from my main form button.

I've read so many answers but it doesn't give me the solution.

My guess in my problem is the following:

1. It is still running because it will not terminate unless all non-daemon threads (my webcam thread?) are closed.
2. OpenCV libraries' fault?

Please refer to my first stackoverflow question link : [MY PROBLEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23507638/java-opencv-videocapture-read-exception-in-thread-java-lang-exception-unkn).java

Thank you,

Comment: In the example code you are swallowing any `InterruptedException` this can cause issues if you are using a thread manager. "The Thread interrupt mechanism is the preferred way to get a (cooperating) thread to respond a request to stop what it is doing"

Comment: Oh okay, thread.interrupt? so i wont be using join()? thank you, ill try

Comment: what version of OpenCV  are you using ?

Comment: I've used thread.interrupt and it works! thanks! and also i now see the "cant sleep" because the thread interrupts right? ok thank you very much!

Comment: Im using the latest version. opencv 2.4.8,

Comment: I suggest taking out the thread sleeps. Why do you sleep 1 second then 20milli then read ?

Comment: Okay i take it out, i've seen the others placing sleep using this code. I've thought it is necessary for it to work. It become faster though. thanks !

Comment: Putting in sleeps so that you can remove them later to speed up the code is a classic optimization trick.